# Animated profile picture on stackexchange.com homepage

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, profile-picture

There's a user on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) named [Oliver Ni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12537/oliver-ni) who has a little almost-white dot on an almost-black background as their profile image. Or so I thought, until glancing at the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/) (on desktop) and seeing a [lively geometrical animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypz5v.gif) in the sidebar. It would seem that while most profile-pic elements in the site look like this:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypz5v.gif?s=16&g=1" alt="Oliver Ni">
```

The ones on the homepage look like this:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypz5v.gif?size=16&g=1" alt="Oliver Ni">
```

Compare [the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypz5v.gif?s=16&g=1) with [the second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypz5v.gif?size=16&g=1). As you can see, imgur doesn't take into account the `size` attribute at all; it should instead be `s`.

Comment: That's.. actually really cool. But should probably be fixed anyway.

Comment: Ha, that *is* neat! Alas, I'll be fixing it tomorrow morning. :)

Comment: LOOK!  ITS FUN!  GET IT!!!!  DESTROY!!!!!

Comment: I'm not Oliver, I'm Oiler V.

Answer (score 6):

I corrected the typo in the parameter and the change is live now.

[image]