# "Top Network Askers" bar shows animated user picture

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, profile-picture

*The grand return of [Animated profile picture on stackexchange.com homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285653/animated-profile-picture-on-stackexchange-com-homepage.)*

Apparently, user [Snow](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/62601/snow) became a Top Network Asker, getting their avatar to show on main SE page. They also happened to have animated profile picture, which does not animate on in almost every place on SE, but does on its main page.

Comment: It seems that it only animates when the "g=1" is removed from the URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2hPC.gif?s=328&g=1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2hPC.gif?s=328

Comment: ...and it seems that the stackexchange.com homepage isn't adding that attribute to the image, unlike the sites; somehow, it's *only* for that image, I looked at others and it *is* adding it to them.