# Period (.) after a link renders after the link in preview, but as part of the link in the rendered post, when there are bold/italic markers

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

This is not a duplicate of [this similar, much older bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179990/why-isnt-the-period-rendered-after-a-question-link), as the Markdown renderers have changed since that report (as a result of the CommonMark transition), and that report was marked completed but this issue has come up again.

When there is a link with a period (full stop) after it, and then one or more asterisks after it (to end bold/italic formatting), the period is rendered after the link (as it should be) in the post preview, but as part of the link in the rendered post.

See the following example (taken from ["Top Network Askers" bar shows animated user picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367021/top-network-askers-bar-shows-animated-user-picture)):

```
*The grand return of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285653/animated-profile-picture-on-stackexchange-com-homepage.*
```

...renders as:

> *The grand return of [Animated profile picture on stackexchange.com homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285653/animated-profile-picture-on-stackexchange-com-homepage)*.

in the preview, with the period after the link, but as:

> *The grand return of [Animated profile picture on stackexchange.com homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285653/animated-profile-picture-on-stackexchange-com-homepage.)*

in the rendered post; notice that the period is incorporated as part of the link, at the end.

The same doesn't happen if there are no asterisks for bold/italic formatting at the end; the period renders correctly after the link and not inside of it:

> The grand return of [Animated profile picture on stackexchange.com homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285653/animated-profile-picture-on-stackexchange-com-homepage).

In the above case, it's benign, but in other cases (e.g. links to external sites), it may cause links to unexpectedly break when the edit is saved. I think it's important to fix bugs relating to differences between the preview and the rendered post, given that the new editor is rolling out and it's not good to show something in the WYSIWYG editor but have it unexpectedly change when the post is saved.